# Overfitting worse with more data

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, natural-language, overfitting

I am training a neural network for a binary text classification task. The network has some custom layers but also includes a full BERT base stack. However, the BERT parameters are fixed, leaving about 6000 additional parameters which are trainable.

I was training the network on a very small dataset of 20 data points, and, with a batch size of 6 and an Adam optimizer with a learning rate of 0.01 and epsilon 1e-07, found overfitting to occur after about 10 epochs (training log loss < 1e-05 while validation log loss > 0.7 and continues to increase with more epochs).

I then increased the size of the training dataset to approximately 25,000 samples and kept the remaining hyperparameters the same. While training, I found overfitting to occur within the first 7-8 *batches* of the first epoch. Again, I am not fine-tuning BERT in either the small or large data regime.

I expected overfitting to be less dramatic on a larger dataset. Why is this not the case?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I don’t remember, but I can try and look back at my code later.

Comment: Please that would be great!!

Comment: did you get a chance to have a look?

Comment: No, sorry, have been busy this week. Looking back, I may not have resolved this issue because I know I did not end up using BERT at the end of the day. Please let me know if you find out what was causing it.

Comment: Thanks! I am not using BERT - but NNLM instead. I will keep at it and report back!